# Trouble with continuous scroll and pagination - Swift UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

This site is awesome.

So I need to create something that looks like this...[image]

It needs to be continuous with a fixed number of UICollectionViewCells (8). It also needs to paginate really well and center the cell (as shown) when the user swipes left or right.

**PROBLEM:** 1. The pagination provided with UICollectionView doesn't center the view on the cell being shown. 2. I'm having a hard time finding the proper way to get the continuous effect.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. This is a tough one!

Comment: Canyon post a bit of the code from your effort related to this. As to achieve this functionalty there are many techniques so it will be better to know what exactly you doing to help you to fix .